# Need help converting column timestamp data into 2 seperate columns (Date,Time)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Fairly new to programming and python in general. Learning as I go. Breaking thing, ALOT, but learning ALOT.

What I want to do, which I have not been able to figure out is create a CSV with certain columns. Currently, one of the columns, after I organize the data, is a date-timestamp, which I need to be separated into 2 columns one for date(yyyy/mm/dd) and one for time (HH:MM:SS 24-hour time). The code looks like this:

```
activities = api.get_activities(
    date='2021-03-09',
    direction='asc',
)

df = pd.DataFrame([activity._raw for activity in activities])
print('created dataframe')

id = df["id"]
activity_type = df["activity_type"]
transaction_time = df["transaction_time"]
type = df["type"]
price = df["price"]
qty = df["qty"]
side = df["side"]
symbol = df["symbol"]
leaves_qty = df["leaves_qty"]
order_id = df["order_id"]
cum_qty = df["cum_qty"]

df[['date', 'time']] = df.transaction_time.str.strip('Z').str.split('T', expand=True)

header = ["date","time","symbol","qty","price","side"]

df.to_csv('daily_journal_export.csv', columns = header, index = False)
print('Completed')
```

When exported I get something that looks like this:

```
transaction_time,symbol,qty,price,side
2021-03-09T15:03:06.0925Z,XNET,5059,6.21,buy
2021-03-09T15:03:06.888595Z,XNET,718,6.21,buy
2021-03-09T15:03:09.474924Z,CLNE,3661,11.65,buy
2021-03-09T15:05:13.957144Z,SOL,1728,12.68,buy
2021-03-09T15:57:53.094945Z,SOL,753,13.33,sell
2021-03-09T15:57:53.118822Z,XNET,5777,6.09,sell
2021-03-09T15:57:53.220454Z,CLNE,3661,11.78,sell
2021-03-09T15:57:53.613874Z,SOL,975,13.33,sell
```

The transaction_time looks like this that needs to be separated and converted:

- Date column: (yyyy/mm/dd)
- Time column: (HH:MM:SS 24-hour time)

**2021-03-09T15:03:06.0925Z**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split()` on the timestamps with the `expand` param (2a below), or use `.dt.date` and `.dt.time` (2b below).

1. Load the sample data:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('daily_journal_export.csv')

    transaction_time                symbol  qty     price   side
0   2021-03-09T15:03:06.0925Z       XNET    5059    6.21    buy
1   2021-03-09T15:03:06.888595Z     XNET    718     6.21    buy
2   2021-03-09T15:03:09.474924Z     CLNE    3661    11.65   buy
3   2021-03-09T15:05:13.957144Z     SOL     1728    12.68   buy
4   2021-03-09T15:57:53.094945Z     SOL     753     13.33   sell
5   2021-03-09T15:57:53.118822Z     XNET    5777    6.09    sell
6   2021-03-09T15:57:53.220454Z     CLNE    3661    11.78   sell
7   2021-03-09T15:57:53.613874Z     SOL     975     13.33   sell
```

2a. Strip the decimals, split by `T`, and expand to separate columns:

```py
>>> df[['date', 'time']] = df.transaction_time.str.replace(r'\..*', '').str.split('T', expand=True)
>>> df = df.drop('transaction_time', axis=1)

    symbol  qty     price   side    date        time
0   XNET    5059    6.21    buy     2021-03-09  15:03:06
1   XNET    718     6.21    buy     2021-03-09  15:03:06
2   CLNE    3661    11.65   buy     2021-03-09  15:03:09
3   SOL     1728    12.68   buy     2021-03-09  15:05:13
4   SOL     753     13.33   sell    2021-03-09  15:57:53
5   XNET    5777    6.09    sell    2021-03-09  15:57:53
6   CLNE    3661    11.78   sell    2021-03-09  15:57:53
7   SOL     975     13.33   sell    2021-03-09  15:57:53
```

2b. **Alternatively,** you can use `.dt.date` and `.dt.time` instead of 2a's string splitting method:

```py
>>> df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.transaction_time).dt.date
>>> df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.transaction_time.str.replace(r'\..*', '')).dt.time
>>> df = df.drop('transaction_time', axis=1)

    symbol  qty     price   side    date        time
0   XNET    5059    6.21    buy     2021-03-09  15:03:06
1   XNET    718     6.21    buy     2021-03-09  15:03:06
2   CLNE    3661    11.65   buy     2021-03-09  15:03:09
3   SOL     1728    12.68   buy     2021-03-09  15:05:13
4   SOL     753     13.33   sell    2021-03-09  15:57:53
5   XNET    5777    6.09    sell    2021-03-09  15:57:53
6   CLNE    3661    11.78   sell    2021-03-09  15:57:53
7   SOL     975     13.33   sell    2021-03-09  15:57:53
```

3. If you want to move `date` and `time` back to the front:

```py
>>> columns = df.columns.to_list()[-2:] + df.columns.to_list()[:-2]
>>> df = df[columns]

    date        time        symbol  qty     price   side
0   2021-03-09  15:03:06    XNET    5059    6.21    buy
1   2021-03-09  15:03:06    XNET    718     6.21    buy
2   2021-03-09  15:03:09    CLNE    3661    11.65   buy
3   2021-03-09  15:05:13    SOL     1728    12.68   buy
4   2021-03-09  15:57:53    SOL     753     13.33   sell
5   2021-03-09  15:57:53    XNET    5777    6.09    sell
6   2021-03-09  15:57:53    CLNE    3661    11.78   sell
7   2021-03-09  15:57:53    SOL     975     13.33   sell
```

Comment: Would I need to do anything to adjust my headers then? 

header = ["transaction_time","symbol","qty","price","side"]


I added new details to my original post.

Comment: Ok I updated the code to deal with the headers in-place (using your new sample data).

Comment: I'm sorry man, I am somewhat lost, again just not very familiar with python and pandas. I can tell you I am giving it my all. I am just not getting the same end result as you are. Is their a way to do that stripping and organizing in my original code rather then making a new python file?

Comment: HOLY #@$#@$R% I DID IT

Comment: Awesome, no problem!

Comment: I got one last question, how can I split and remove everything after the period in the time? I updated my original post to show you what I added to my code. In this example, 15:03:06.0925 everything including and after the '.' would need to be removed, ".0925"

Comment: In step 2a, you can change the `str.strip('Z')` to `str.replace(r'\..*', '')`. I updated the code in 2a which should do what you want.